# How to get a result for the below table using teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I am new to Teradata. I have created the table with empno, mobile and office no as follows. I need mobile and office no in separate column.

```
empno mobile office
111    9999  4444
222    null  3333
333    5555  7896
444    6666  null
```

I need to have output as:

```
111 9999
111 4444
222 3333
333 5555 
333 7896
444 6666
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT empno, mobile FROM t WHERE mobile IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT empno, office FROM t WHERE office IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY empno;
```

This is not Teradata-specific, works for any SQL database.